# Error: Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic6

Am using ionic/angular version 6, but the image that I have set as background picture is fail to be loaded from the assets folder, the path to the image file is correct.   `--background: #ccc url("../../assets/images/background.jpg") no-repeat center center / cover;`

With the url file path expect, image as the background and not the error of Module Error.

Answer (score -1):

you can try:

background-image: url(/assets/images/background.jpg);

in your css file. This works for me.

Comment: If you are uncertain about the details of the question, please consider leaving a comment with any observations or questions you may have, rather than writing an answer. This can help clarify any misunderstandings and ensure that the answer provided is accurate and helpful.